# limit of the sequence defined recursively

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am having problem in the following problem.

> $x_0=0,\ x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{3}{2}x_n-\frac{1}{2}x_{n-1}\ n\ge 1.$ Then how will I prove that the sequence is convergent and what will be its limit.

I am not able to proceed. Please help!

Comment: Is the idea to do this without finding the actual explicit form of the sequence? The solution (which you could figure out yourself by using WolframAlpha) is $x_n = 2-2^{1-n}$.

Comment: Sorry, but from the answer given I am able to get $x_{n+1}-x_n=2^{-n}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{3}{2}x_{n} - \frac{1}{2}x_{n-1}$$
This recursive pattern can be converted into
$$x_{n+1} - x_{n} = \frac{1}{2}(x_{n} - x_{n-1}) $$
This is an geometric progression. Maybe you are familiar with this pattern.

Comment: I am able to get $x_{n+1}-x_n=2^{-n}$. From this I can conclude that the sequence is Cauchy and hence convergent but how will I find the limit?

Comment: You can compute like this $$x_{n+1} - x_{n} = 2^{-n}, x_{n} - x_{n-1} = 2^{-(n-1)}, .... $$

Comment: Keep in mind that $x_n-x_0 = \sum_{k=1}^n [x_k-x_{k-1}]$.